# Placing text widget in frame in notebook in TCL

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have an application in TCL that has a notebook with 3 tabs. I'm trying to place a text widget in one of the tabs but I can't for the life of me get it to work. The notebook shows fine with:

```
ttk::notebook .n -width 950 -height 750
ttk::frame .n.fr;
ttk::frame .n.fr1;
ttk::frame .n.fr2;
```

The tabs show fine with:

```
.n add .n.fr -text "Tab A"
.n add .n.fr1 -text "Tab B"
.n add .n.fr2 -text "Tab C"

pack .n
```

I want to place a text widget into Tab B but everything I've tried doesn't work, everywhere I've looked explains everything except how to do this. Clearly it is a very simple formula to get this to embed in the frame in the notebook (Tab B) but I cannot seem to happen upon it. Can anyone tell what the formula for doing this is?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create one with a window name consisting of the parent frame, and the name of your text widget.

For example:

```
text .n.fr1.t   ;# Create the text widget .n.fr1.t into .n.fr1
pack .n.fr1.t   ;# Draw it
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Programming I can handle, interfaces are continually confounding.

Comment: @CoderMojo Yea, I'm mostly the same. I can't say I grasp interface design enough yet myself.